# Streaming video from S3 bucket not working on Safari browser

Tags: php, amazon-s3, video-streaming

I am trying to serve video content that is hosted on AWS S3 via PHP and the AWS SDK.

The solution that I currently have works perfectly for Chrome and Firefox. However on Safari and Iphone fails.

I have already tried the proposed solution from this guide: https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

Using this guide no video is streamed back.

Here is my current code that allows me to stream code on Chrome and Firefox

```php
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
$this->s3->registerStreamWrapper();
if ($stream = fopen("s3://$this->bucket_name/$key", 'r')) {
  while (!feof($stream)) {
   echo fread($stream, 1024);
  }
  fclose($stream);
}
```

Comment: Are you using CloudFront?

Comment: Nope, its basic access of the S3 bucket.

Comment: Why are you proxying the data?  Why not just sign the URL and let S3 serve it?

Comment: Well I am not sure if I fully understand you but I want to stream it since it becomes consumed by video HTML tag. I don't know if the URL: serve the content type as well. I could try!